# Is a DSLR required for making a DIY 3D scanner?

Tags: nikon, diy, scanner, coolpix

I've been looking into this- making my own 3d scanner for my 3d printer- and all the DIY instructions require a DSLR... but they don't explain why- exactly.

Maybe it has something to do with "seeing" the depth of the laser cross section of the 3d object being scanned?

Anyway, I have a rather dated Nikon L20 Coolpix- and was trying to determine if it was a DSLR or not- and if it would be usable in this application. No rangefinder at all- I don't think any mirrors either-

- So I guess my main question is: why do you suppose the laser line scanning requires any of that stuff- and would my humble digital camera be up to the task?

Comment: I do not know which DIY instructions you've read, so can't judge why they direct you to a DSLR. However, it might have something to do with the fact that DSLR's allow for manual focus, full manual exposure controls and (often) tethering to a computer.

Comment: No. You can do a 3D scanner with your phone if you want. http://www.123dapp.com/catch

Answer (score 2):

A DSLR is not **required** for 3D scanning. With simple, low-poly scans, you're better off with a multi-sensor array like a Kinect or Leap-Motion. However, for ultra-high quality, high-poly scans, a camera like a DSLR would be advantageous. a Nikon L20 Coolpix is not a DSLR, but it will serve the purpose with its 10.34MP sensor.