# Using multiple cameras at same time

Tags: tethering

[This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70211/is-a-dslr-required-for-making-a-diy-3d-scanner?rq=1) asked regarding 3D scanning raised my question:

Is it possible to operate multiple cameras at the same time?

Background: I have Canon EOS 750D and I can operate it via USB cable and EOS utility software.

Is it possible to connect several cameras of any brand (say, all Nikons; Hasselblads; Sony and Pentax;...) to the PC and control them simultaneously. Not just to pull the trigger; I'd like to set all the cameras at once (apperture, shutter, ISO) with respect to the mode they are switched to (P/A/S/M).

Comment: If it doesn't, Canon does offer an SDK. So something could always be made or contracted.

Comment: *EOS Utility* only allows one camera at a time to be tethered to the application. As @CrazyDino mentions, the Canon SDK *may* allow you to create an app that can do more than one. But it also might not.

Comment: Almost by definition, if it is possible to create an app that can control one, it is possible to spawn multiple instances of that app to control more than one, and there's no reason those instances can't talk to each other.  Whether they make it easy to do so or not is another question.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but not using EOS Utility. There are some software packages out there that can manage multiple cameras at once:

- [Breeze Systems](https://www.breezesys.com/MultiCamera/release.htm) offers products for triggering multiple cameras.
- [digicamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com) is free, open source software that can manage multiple cameras.
- Many radio triggers such as PocketWizards can be used to trigger cameras as well as flashes, and multiple triggers can be set to simultaneously trigger the cameras they're connected to.

Answer (score 4):

You can control any mix of cameras using software like [DSLR Remote Pro Multi-Camera](http://breezesys.com/MultiCamera/index.htm) by Breeze System, [Smart Shooter](https://kuvacode.com/smart-shooter) by Kuvacode and [Xangle](https://shop.ericpare.com/collections/xangle/products/xangle-bullet-time-software) by Eric Pare.

The ESPER [TriggerBox](https://www.esperhq.com/product/triggerbox-multiple-camera-trigger/) would be suitable for triggering multi-camera setups. Up to 6 cameras can be triggered per box and multiple units can be linked together to trigger larger number of cameras like 3d scanning setup or 360 bullet-time array. You can use it to fire all DSLRs at once or with programmed sequences and offsets.

Breeze has produced an [article](http://breezesys.com/MultiCamera/release.htm) on the various methods to trigger all the cameras at the same time.